# Is there anyway to get edge betweenness of edge in python?

Tags: python, networkx

Seems like networkx already have some good features to show betweenness centrality.
But is there any way to get some values of  edge betweenness of edge in python?

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.DiGraph()
edge=[(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(2,4),(3,5),(4,5),(4,6),(6,7),(6,8)]
G.add_edges_from(edge)
```

this is an example and I want to get edge betwenness of (4,6)

Comment: And why not use `nx.edge_betweenness_centrality` exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after do some searching, It seems like using igraph is way better in this situation.

```
from igraph import *
g = Graph([(1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,4), (3,5), (4,5), (4,6), (6,7), (6,8)])
g.edge_betweenness()
```

[4.5, 2.0, 3.5, 6.5, 5.0, 10.5, 15.0, 7.0, 7.0]

So... yeah...this much simple one, I can use just igraph in python..